# Is it possible to mount AWS FSX storage on a docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cloud, storage, devops

Is it possible to mount an AWS FSX Windows storage on top of a docker container on an AWS EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are running Samba client within the Docker container then yes, you probably can.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve ? If your aim is to somehow expose the SAMBA shares outside of the AWS environment for easy consumption then you could do that with The File Fabric from SME. As I recall they host their environment in a Docker container on AWS but EC2 but their API provides access to FSX shares from web or mobile, or a FUSE based desktop share (over https).